# Automapper and Custom Type Converter with Parent/Child

Tags: automapper

How can I covert am object to a certain type based on a property of the parent object holding the current object with automapper?

Below I have a class that contains a property called `Type` of enum type `EventAssetType`.  I want to convert the property `Asset` to a type called `DocumentModel` or `ImageModel` that both inherit from `AssetModel` by using the `Type` property.  Right now it is just mappering from `Asset` to `AssetModel`.

```
public class EventAssetModel
{
    public EventAssetModel()
    {
        Event = new EventModel();
        Asset = new DocumentModel();
        Type = Enums.EventAssetType.Other;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public Enums.EventAssetType Type { get; set; }

    public EventModel Event { get; set; }
    public AssetModel Asset { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is the `ConvertUsing` extension method when creating a map.  I've included an example for you below:

```
namespace Some.Namespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Animal>().ConvertUsing(MappingFunction);

            Source animal = new Source() {Type = Source.SourceType.Animal, Name = "Some Animal"};
            Source dog = new Source() {Type = Source.SourceType.Dog, Name = "Fido"};

            Animal convertedAnimal = Mapper.Map<Source, Animal>(animal);
            Console.WriteLine(convertedAnimal.GetType().Name + " - " + convertedAnimal.Name);
            // Prints 'Animal - Some Animal'

            Animal convertedDog = Mapper.Map<Source, Animal>(dog);
            Console.WriteLine(convertedDog.GetType().Name + " - " + convertedDog.Name);
            // Prints 'Dog - Fido'
        }

        private static Animal MappingFunction(Source source)
        {
            switch (source.Type)
            {
                    case Source.SourceType.Animal:
                    return new Animal() {Name = source.Name};
                    case Source.SourceType.Dog:
                    return new Dog() {Name = source.Name};
            }
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Source
    {
        public enum SourceType
        {
            Animal,
            Dog
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public SourceType Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Animal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dog : Animal
    {
        // Specific Implementation goes here
    }
}
```